# Find property with value of true and return its message

Tags: javascript, object

Supposed I have an object of

```
let testObj = {
    keys : {
                chkkeys : false, 
                msg : 'test one'
    },
    grtr    : {
                chkgrtr : true,
                msg : 'test two'
    },
    empt    : {
                chkEmpt : false,
                msg : 'test three'
    }
}
```

How can I find the property with a value of true and return its message

For example this is the only true `chkgrtr : true` therefore the value should be return is `'test two'`

this is what I have tried so far

```
Object.keys(testObj).forEach((item) => {
    Object.keys(testObj[item]).forEach((sI) => {
        if (testObj[item][sI] === true) {
            return testObj[item]['sMsg'];
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `Object.values` of the `testObj`, `.find` the one with a property, other than `msg`, which has a value of `true`, and return its `msg`:

```js
let testObj = {
  keys: {
    chkkeys: false,
    msg: 'test one'
  },
  grtr: {
    chkgrtr: true,
    msg: 'test two'
  },
  empt: {
    chkEmpt: false,
    msg: 'test three'
  }
};

const foundObj = Object.values(testObj)
  .find(obj => Object.entries(obj)
    .some(([key, val]) => key !== 'msg' && val)
  );
if (foundObj) {
  console.log(foundObj.msg);
}
```

This is a *pretty weird* object structure, though. If at all possible, it'd probably be better to change it so that all keys are the same, while only changing the values. Eg, the objects could be

```
  empt: {
    chk: false,
    name: 'empt', // put the variable key here, if you actually need it
    msg: 'test three'
  }
```

Then all you have to do is `.find(obj => obj.chk)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array.prototype.find` instead of `forEach`. that would solve it for you.

```
Object.keys(testObj).find((item) => {
    return Object.keys(testObj[item]).find((sI) => {
        if (testObj[item][sI] === true) {
            return testObj[item]['sMsg'];
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Object.entries()** May help you in this case.

    let testObj = {
    keys : {
                chkkeys : false, 
                msg : 'test one'
    },
    grtr    : {
                chkgrtr : true,
                msg : 'test two'
    },
    empt    : {
                chkEmpt : false,
                msg : 'test three'
    }
}
let Entries = Object.entries(testObj);
for(var i = 0; i<Entries.length; i++){
    if(Object.entries(Entries[i][1])[0][1]===true){
      console.log(Entries[i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional way:

```
Object.values(testObj).find(value=> value[Object.keys(value).find(key=>key != 'msg')]).msg
```